# Writing a function to prevent redundancy

Tags: javascript

I am just getting into Javascript and I think what I am working on can be made less redundant by using a function, however I am unsure how to construct it. I am **not** asking for someone to write the function for me, but rather get me on the right track.

The goal of my project is to be able map dynamic textures to each cube, with each cube leading to a unique link.
Using [this](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_cubes) example, I have been able to successfully map a unique texture to each cube, but as I mentioned before, my solution is horribly redundant.

```
       for ( var i = 0; i < 16; i++ ) {




   var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materialArray[0]);
          object.position.x = Math.random() * 800;
          object.position.y = Math.random() * 800;
          object.position.z = Math.random() * 800;

          object.rotation.x = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
          object.rotation.y = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
          object.rotation.z = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;

          object.scale.x = Math.random() + 0.5;
          object.scale.y = Math.random() + 0.5;
          object.scale.z = Math.random() + 0.5;

          object.name ="object";

   var object2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materialArray[1] );
          object2.position.x = Math.random() * 800 - 400;
          object2.position.y = Math.random() * 800 - 400;
          object2.position.z = Math.random() * 800 - 400;

          object2.rotation.x = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
          object2.rotation.y = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
          object2.rotation.z = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;

          object2.scale.x = Math.random() + 0.5;
          object2.scale.y = Math.random() + 0.5;
          object2.scale.z = Math.random() + 0.5;

           object2.name ="object2";

     var object3 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materialArray[2] );
          object3.position.x = Math.random() * 800 - 400;
          object3.position.y = Math.random() * 800 - 400;
          object3.position.z = Math.random() * 800 - 400;

          object3.rotation.x = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
          object3.rotation.y = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
          object3.rotation.z = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;

          object3.scale.x = Math.random() + 0.5;
          object3.scale.y = Math.random() + 0.5;
          object3.scale.z = Math.random() + 0.5;

           object3.name ="object3";

    var object4 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materialArray[3] );
          object4.position.x = Math.random() * 800 - 400;
          object4.position.y = Math.random() * 800 - 400;
          object4.position.z = Math.random() * 800 - 400;

          object4.rotation.x = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
          object4.rotation.y = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
          object4.rotation.z = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;

          object4.scale.x = Math.random() + 0.5;
          object4.scale.y = Math.random() + 0.5;
          object4.scale.z = Math.random() + 0.5;

           object4.name ="object4";

    var object5 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materialArray[4] );
          object5.position.x = Math.random() * 800 - 400;
          object5.position.y = Math.random() * 800 - 400;
          object5.position.z = Math.random() * 800 - 400;

          object5.rotation.x = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
          object5.rotation.y = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
          object5.rotation.z = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;

          object5.scale.x = Math.random() + 0.5;
          object5.scale.y = Math.random() + 0.5;
          object5.scale.z = Math.random() + 0.5;

           object5.name ="object5";

}
```

I have created an array of materials so I am able to reference a unique material for each cube, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this for the objects. I believe writing a function to generate the objects is the solution, just need a hint to get me on the right track.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code works, and as such belongs on CodeReview.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it's pretty literally copy&paste. Since the code doesn't really reference too much, it's easy to pass the needed variables as arguments:

```
function createMesh(name, geometry, material) {
     var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
     object.position.x = Math.random() * 800 - 400;
     object.position.y = Math.random() * 800 - 400;
     object.position.z = Math.random() * 800 - 400;

     object.rotation.x = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
     object.rotation.y = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
     object.rotation.z = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;

     object.scale.x = Math.random() + 0.5;
     object.scale.y = Math.random() + 0.5;
     object.scale.z = Math.random() + 0.5;

     object.name = name;
}
```

Then it'd be pretty simple to use it in a loop:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 5; ++i) {
    createMesh("object" + i, geometry, materialArray[i]);
}
```

I'd also think about writing utilities for random position and rotation:

```
function randomRotation() {
     var rotation = {};
     rotation.x = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
     rotation.y = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
     rotation.z = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
}

function randomPosition(min, max) {
    var position = {};
    position.x = Math.random() * (max.x-min.x) + min.x;
    position.y = Math.random() * (max.y-min.y) + min.y;
    position.z = Math.random() * (max.z-min.z) + min.z;
}
```

Which you can then use:

```
object.rotation = randomRotation();
object.position = randomPosition({x: -400, y: -400, z: -400}, {x: 400, y: 400, z: 400});
```

Comment: After implementing this solution, it gives me "Cannot set property of 'x' of undefined" in the createMesh function where I declare the objects x,y and z positions. Shouldn't I be declaring my object as a global variable and not a local one?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

It iterates over the callback object and takes the key and then iterates ober the given obejct and assign the called callback for every property in the object.

```js
var object = {
        position: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 },
        rotation: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 },
        scale: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }
    },
    callback = {
        position: function () { return Math.random() * 800; },
        rotation: function () { return Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI; },
        scale: function () { return Math.random() + 0.5; }
    }

function set(object, cb) {
    Object.keys(cb).forEach(function (k) {
        Object.keys(object[k]).forEach(function (kk) {
            object[k][kk] = cb[k]();
        });
    });
}

set(object, callback);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```